# Can we access the elements in a Hashtable in java using an index instead of a key?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I have a hashtable declared as :

```
Hashtable<Integer, ArrayList<String>> writeData = new Hashtable<>();
```

I want to access the contents of `writeData` so as to print them one by one. I don't know what the keys are. So printing them using the keys is not a good idea. Is there a better way to implement Hashtables?

Comment: why do yo want to use hashtable now..you can go with hashmap

Comment: I am not getting the right way to implement Hashmap here. Can we get a value in hashmap using an index?

Comment: no but you can get the set of keys and print the corresponding data.or you can iterate using EntrySet in hasmao and get both key and value

Comment: I think this can work  ---- >  for (Map.Entry me : writeData.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: "+me.getKey() + " & Value: " + me.getValue());
        }